# Who were the highest-ranking officers of each belligerent nation, who parachuted with troops in Operation Market Garden?

Tags: world-war-two

1. Was erstwhile (MG) [James M. Gavin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_M._Gavin#Early_life) the highest-ranking US general officer?
2. Please see the question's title. I know that U.K. soldiers parachuted, but don't know if any Canadians, Polish did.

> Gavin assumed command of the 82nd Airborne Division on August 8, 1944, and was promoted to major general in October.[[9]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_M._Gavin#cite_note-9) For the first time, Gavin would lead the 82nd Airborne into combat. On Sunday, September 17, [Operation Market Garden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Market_Garden) took off. Market Garden, devised by [Field Marshal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_marshal_(United_Kingdom)) [Bernard Montgomery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernard_Montgomery,_1st_Viscount_Montgomery_of_Alamein), consisted of an airborne attack of three British and American airborne divisions. The 82nd was to take the bridge across the Maas river in [Grave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave,_Netherlands), seize at least one of four bridges across the Maas-Waal canal, and the bridge across the Waal river in [Nijmegen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nijmegen). The 82nd was also to take control of the high grounds in the vicinity of Groesbeek, a small Dutch town near the German border. The ultimate objective of the offensive was [Arnhem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Arnhem).
>
> In the drop into the Netherlands, Gavin landed on hard pavement instead of grass, injuring his back. He had it inspected by a doctor a few days later, who claimed that his back was fine, and so Gavin continued normally throughout the entirety of the war. Five years later, he had his back examined at [Walter Reed Hospital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_Reed_Hospital), where he learned that he had, in fact, fractured two discs in the jump.[[10]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_M._Gavin#cite_note-10)

Answer (score 5):

#### Overall Command

- [Lieutenant General Browning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederick_Browning#Operation_Market_Garden) glided in near Nijmegen the first day commanding British I Airborne Corps and deputy commander of 1st Allied Airborne Army, to be tactical (on the ground) commander for all Allied airborne forces in **Operation Market** (the airborne component of [**Market Garden**)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Market_Garden).

#### 82nd Airborne

- [Brigadier General James M. Gavin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_M._Gavin#Operation_Market_Garden) parachuted in commanding U.S. 82nd Airborne, not being promoted to Major General until October 1944, a month after Market Garden.

#### 101st Airborne (US)

- [Major General Maxwell D. Taylor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_D._Taylor#101st_Airborne_Division) landed commanding the 101st Airborne but I am not sure yet whether he parachuted or glided in.

  However Taylor was a trained and accomplished parachutist, having successfully jumped into Normandy 6 months earlier as commander of the 101st, so I have no reason to doubt that he again jumped into battle as commander of the 101st during Market Garden.

#### 1st Airborne (British)

- [Major General Roy Urquhart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roy_Urquhart#Arnhem) glided in commanding British 1st Airborne.
- [Brigadier General Hicks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_Hugh_Whitby_Hicks#Second_World_War) was his deputy commander and commander of British 1st Airlanding Brigade, and also arrived that day at Arnhem by glider.
- I have not yet identified the commanding officers of the two component airborne brigades, 1st and 4th, both of whom would have parachuted in.

#### Polish Brigade

- [Brigadier General Stanislaw Sosabowski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanis%C5%82aw_Sosabowski#Warsaw_Uprising) parachuted down with the Polish 1st Independent Parachute brigade.

Comment: @Tom: Thanks for the catch. Corrected.

Comment: 1st Parachute Brigade - Brigadier Gerald Lathbury, 4th Parachute Brigade - Brigadier John W. Hackett - Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Market_Garden_order_of_battle#British_I_Airborne_Corps

Answer (score 1):

There is already an answer for the Allies. You might want to note that Major General Urquhart had never parachuted nor landed before.

On the German side, there is Model, a former Eastern Front commander, Student, former airborne troops commander who said "If only I had such means" when he saw Allied airborne troops during Market Garden, and the SS general Bittrich.